# Routing or Resolv? issues with host network and guest ubuntu 16.04/18.04

Tags: dns, routing

To be honest I'm not really sure what to ask specificly. I'll just describe the problem I'm having and I need some help debugging it. We've been using Ubuntu 14.04 for an embedded development project in a VM. Everything works fine. When I'm at home and connect to the VPN it resolves server names great. Our debugging users g_ether over local link 168.254.x.x IP address and with it connected to the host machine I can connect to it perfectly fine with ubuntu 14.04.

This is using a network NAT device only. Save settings moving to ubuntu 16.04/18.04. 16.04 completely doesn't work. I can't ping servers by name over vpn or ping the local link to 169.254.x.x times out. I can ping the server IP's directly... I see 18.04 recently came out so figure git it a try... 18.04 out of the box worked like 14.04 but after a few days same behavior as 16.04.

Any ideas what it might be?

One of the 'similar questions' is catching my attention, I'll check this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829204/dns-routing-fails-for-vpn-connections-on-ubuntu-16-04-out-of-the-box) in the mean time.

**Update:**

It seems as though there is an issue with ubuntu 16.04/18.04 updating routing tables or network settings in general.

Basically if I turn the VM on while being on the domain, or having the device plugged in, the network device will permanently have the search domain added, and the IP in the routing table permanently. If neither are available neither setting will be added nor will ever be added.

So I think I can get around this issue by making a rule for the routing table and permanently adding the domain as a search domain... once I figure out how to do that.